# Root password keep changing

Tags: root

This is frustrating. I am often able to login with a root password. Then I cannot login again. However, I am still logged in. Hence my password must be correct.

I changed the root password with `passwd`. It works again. Then sometimes latter this happens again.

It's as if the root password changes all the time automatically. Did someone hack my server?

Comment: Just a short note: a password change does not close the existing sessions. The fact you're still logged in does not mean that the password at any given time is the same that you have used to log in.

Comment: It's not that the password keeps changing. It seems that server reject all root login for a few hours and stuff.

Comment: /var/messages are indeed full with so many failed login attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming someone is playing around with your box or some kind of practical joke, and they did not cover their track.

## Check login history

### Via Command Line

```
w
last
```

### Via Log Files

```
/var/log/auth.log (debian/ubuntu)
/var/log/secure (RedHat/CentOS/Fedora?)
```

## Other Possibilities

1. Your box is a virtual machine and some how keep getting roll back to previous state(snapshot).
2. Many VPS actually reset your root password. You have to use the vendor/hosting web interface to change the root password. Otherwise it will just keep changing back to the previous one.

Comment: how do I know my server's IP? Maybe I am logged in to a different machine

Comment: Login in as root, type command `ifconfig`. If you are using a windows machine, go to website whatismyip.com

Comment: @JimThio I have the following command readily available; it will print the *external* IP address that you are using to make outbound connections, thus taking into account NAT etc. `wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain` That's just one service to obtain one's IP address; there are numerous others. `-q` means use quiet mode, and `-O-` means print the content of the response to `-` (standard output) rather than saving it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share what's going on.

I am the one that make the question and this is a very old recurring problems.

The issue can be seen here:

http://hostechs.com/2008/10/user-root-blocked-cphulk-brute-force-protection/

I am using cpanel.

Cpanel has cphulk that protects machines from brute force loging.

The problem is,

Many people have had the same problem. THe solution is to ensure that your IP is white listed by cphulk. Also rebooting the machine may sometimes work for a while. There is no easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

While reviewing other posts concerning this issue, I ran across information concerning how to check the system for an infection ..

Run either program:

```
rkhunter  
chkrootkit
```

verify the integrity of binaries

```
rpm -Va .
```

Confirm all root owned files that have the suid bit turned on. Any such file is executed as root, no matter who the user is. Use:

```
find / -perm 4755
```

A resulting file will have rwsr-x-r-x permissions.  The "s" tells you the suid bit is turned on. Because it has execute by ANY users (the final r-x) it means any user can run it as root. I run the find for each of 4777, 4775, 4755 etc... - basically for any mode in which anyone other than the user (root) would be able to write the file (so no reason to search for 4744 because though it is readable by everyone else only root could write to it.)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/root-password-keeps-changing-372647/

Also to reset your passwords:
From GRUB boot menu, add to linux16 line ...

```
rw init=/bin/bash
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>

reset root password

```
passwd
```

reset user password

```
passwd [user]
touch / .autorelabel
/sbin/reboot -f
```

http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/03/19/how-to-reset-passwords-on-fedora-21-and-22/

Also, found the Linux.Xor.DDoS trogan on affected systems. Still searching how to remove it. But, an effective way to keep it from getting in is using private keys.

If you also have an SSH server running make sure to set up key authentication with a strong password, then turn off just password authentication. This forces SSH to authentic witht the public/private keys you set up. Makes it next to impossible to brute force since the attacker won't have the appropriate key and the system will just drop the connection.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Follow the instruction to enter a pass phrase and store the key into a file. Now copy the key to the computer you want to ssh to:

```
ssh-copy-id username@remote_host
```

Finally, with the key transfered, you should be able to log in with:

```
ssh username@remote_host
```

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/562586/the-newly-discovered-xorddos-trojan-infects-linux-systems-to-possibly-build-an/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-ssh-configuration-keypairs.html

To disable SSH password authentication:

```
cd /etc/ssh
cp sshd_config sshd_config.orig
vi sshd_config
```

Change the following settings

```
PermitRootLogin     no
PasswordAuthentication  no
UsePAM          no
```

Restart SSH

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-debian-etch

Comment: @STephen Rauch, thank you for updating the post, and making the links active.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there's another machine on the network with the same IP address and they're fighting. Sometimes you login to your server, sometimes to the rogue.

Comment: If you use ssh to log in, then you should be able to tell if this is happening from the host key changing.