# root password suddenly invalid

Tags: password, root, authentication

I can't use my former root password anymore.

System: Debian Testing

What did I do:

- log into root
- doing updates (with `aptitude update && aptitude upgrade`)
- `aptitude install cryptsetup`
- starting encryption by triple-checked `cryptsetup -c aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 -y -s 256 luksFormat /dev/sdc7`

Checked:

- date and time of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are like before
- no typing error (typed vissible)
- no one else logged in (`last`)
- **not possible:** `/var/log/auth.log` (needs su rights)

Could the upgrade corrupt the password? (Help for resetting the password isn't needed, I think the old root shell "feature" still works.)

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60237/root-password-keep-changing?rq=1)

Comment: What's in `/dev/sdc7`?

Comment: @terdon: a new external harddrive with no data on it.

Comment: @somethingSomething: thx for the hint. In that case its a network problem. I am working locally, direct on the machine. User password is still working. Unfortunatly, I have no rights to look at `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success: Typing the password the next day, revealed, that my procedural (typing) memory access was working again and I used the <kbd>Shift</kbd> once more. So it was merely a typo. Good luck to all up-voters of the question :)

(Procedural memory is different from the declarative or explicit or verbal memory. Expect bugs in both features, when having a hard time recalling a password :)